# Flutter with VS Code and emulator taking too much ram

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, android-emulator

I just want to ask, im running flutter with vs code and android emulator using my Acer Aspire 3 (Ryzen 5 2500u and 8gb ram 6.9gb usable).
When i run the emulator suddenly my laptop was slow and when i check task manager my ram usage is reaching 98-99% due these Open JDK, vscode, emulator, dart, etc. Is it normal? I saw the requirement on flutter website and i think my spec its not problem. Any one know how to fix this issue?
Sorry for my bad English Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

This is a very common issue that I faced personally. After wasting a lot of time at the slow laptop, I decided to upgrade my RAM & now it works better.

Assuming that a normal Flutter developer uses the following programs at any given time -

**Chrome (~1.5 GB)**

(Obviously for StackOverflow, Github, Music, Surfing etc. Minimum 5 - 8 tabs open)

**VS Code (~1 - 2 GB)**

For running project(s) (Sometimes I have to switch b/w multiple projects)

**Emulator (~1.5 - 2 GB)**

Easily consumes a lot of RAM.

**Your OS (Windows/Linux/Mac (~1.5 - 2 GB)**

Your OS may consume 1.5 - 2 GB RAM with no programs running. If it is consuming more, then try restarting your laptop.

I have upgraded my RAM to 16 GB now. Now, my normal usage goes to 7.6 GB (around 50% RAM usage).

If you are using Android Studio, then you will have even less RAM. It is really heavy (2.5 GB+, in some cases). I personally use VS Code as it is light-weight.

Comment: Actually i've tried to close all software including my browser, but still. I think i have to upgrade my ram too, just confuse because people says 8gb ram is enough for flutter with emulator.

Comment: As you can see, we are left with almost no memory. So, 8 GB is not enough. When my laptop was new, I was also able to code with no problems but after a few months, my laptop became slow so I upgraded the RAM.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative can be to use an actual mobile device, instead of an emulator.

Answer (score 0):

My computer with Intel Core i7 - 4770 and 12 GB RAM is much worse.
Android Tablet Emulator used up to 3.96GB RAM. 8 Tasks of Dart.exe used up to 3.6GB of RAM. VSCode only used up 1.6GB. I only open one Flutter project, one Node.js project.

I used the recent version of Flutter 3.04. The computer is so much slow and very lag. I only opened one Edge browser too. I really hope Flutter team can fix this thing. I don't have any budget yet to buy Android tablet for this startup project. Android emulator is my only option.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32223997)

Comment: I am sorry. I didn't know the rule.

Comment: That’s fine; we’re here to help you learn them. Stack Overflow doesn’t work like a typical discussion board, and that’s a good thing. But it does take some getting used to.